# Every time a new password is generated while decrypting at login

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I encrypted the password and stored it in db.But while decrypting at the time of login it is generating every time a new pass that's it does not match with the pass stored in db.I used SimpleCrypto class.
How can  i resolve this issue??

Comment: Show the code that you are using to encrypt, decrypt, verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you `compute` the pass also pass the PasswordSalt u generated while registeration

```
var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();
```

now get the PasswordSalt from Database and pass it like this

```
var pas = crypto.Compute(pass,pass_salt);
```